Maximum work (free energy) from the fundamental thermodynamic relation
I want to derive the maximum (free) work function $M$:
$$M=U_1-U_2 +p_s(V_1-V_2) -T_{s}(S_1-S_2)$$
where the variables with the index $1$ represent the initial state of the system and the variables labeled with the index $2$ represent the final state when the system has reached thermal and mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings. The index $s$ stands for surroundings.
From the fundamental relation:
$$dU=TdS-pdV$$
$$0=-dU-pdV+TdS$$
I define $\delta M$ (inexact differential of the Maximum work, it is not a state variable) as :
$$\delta M :=-dU-pdV+TdS $$
After integrating I obtain:
$$M=-\Delta U-p\Delta V+T\Delta S$$
$$M=U_1-U_2+p_s(V_1-V_2) -T_s (S_1-S_2)>0$$
Which was what we wanted.
My question:
My argument and this derivation of $M$ is heavily influenced by what I chose to be as my definition for the infinitesimal from of the Maximum work function $\delta M$.
I have trouble finding the derivation of this function (all the articles are about the Gibbs free energy), and they also don't provide a clear starting ground for a derivation.
Can someone please confirm or challenge this approach and provide the standard way of deriving it if this is not rigorous enough?

Are you saying you want to derive Gibbs free energy?

@BobD Well, yes. Although this expression also includes pressure-volume work.

The formula for GIbbs free energy includes pv work.

Consider a system in thermal contact with a heat bath at temperature $T$, with both thermally isolated from the rest of the universe.  For an infinitesimal step in an arbitrary process taking the system from state 1 to state 2, assume the entropy change of the universe is the sum of the changes in the system and the bath:
$dS_{univ} = dS + dS_{bath}$.
Define our sign conventions such that the first law is written
$dU = -dW + dQ$,
i.e. $dW$ is work done by the system and $dQ$ is heat into the system.  These depend on the particular process, but $dU$ does not.  Hence
\begin{equation} 
-dW + dQ = -dW^{rev} + dQ^{rev}. \; (1)
\end{equation}
Note that for a reversible process, $dQ^{rev} = -dQ_{bath}^{rev}$, where $dQ_{bath}$ is the heat into the bath, and for a general process, $dQ_{bath} \ge dQ_{bath}^{rev}$ (because $dS_{bath} \ge dS_{bath}^{rev}$).  So
$dQ_{bath} \ge dQ_{bath}^{rev} = -dQ^{rev}$.
Then the entropy change of the universe is
\begin{eqnarray*}
dS + dS_{bath} &=& dS + \dfrac{dQ_{bath}}{T}\\
               &\ge& dS + \dfrac{dQ_{bath}^{rev}}{T}\\
               &=& dS - \dfrac{dQ^{rev}}{T}\\
               &=& dS - \dfrac{dU + dW^{rev}}{T}\\
               &=& -\dfrac{\left(dU + dW^{rev} - TdS\right)}{T}.
\end{eqnarray*}
If this last quantity is positive, then the process step corresponds to a positive definite change in entropy of the universe.  Note that all differentials in this expression are process-independent, and only depend on the initial and final states, so let's define the quantity in parentheses as the differential of a state function and call it generically "free energy" or "availability" $A$ (never mind whether Helmhotz, Gibbs, etc., which are special cases).  The maximum work available in going from 1 to 2, then (your $M$) is $M = -\int_1^2 dA$, and $\delta M = -dA$.  Thus
$dA = dU + dW^{rev} - TdS$.
If this is negative, then the differential step in the change of state can occur spontaneously, since it corresponds to an increase of entropy of the universe.
It remains to specify in a given situation what means of doing reversible work the system has, in terms of its macrovariables.
If there is no way of doing reversible work, $dW^{rev} = 0$, and $dA = dU - TdS = dF = $ Helmholtz free energy.
If the system can do PV work by expanding or being compressed, then $dW^{rev} = PdV$.  Then we call $dU + dW^{rev} = dU + PdV \equiv dH$ the differential enthalpy, and $dA = dH - TdS = dG = $ the Gibbs free energy.
If the system can do reversible chemical work as well, then we include $-\sum \mu_i dN_i$, so $dA = dU + PdV - \sum \mu_i dN_i - TdS$.
etc.

Thanks for the answer. I think there is just one problem. Desipte the fact that all differentials in $\delta M$ (or in your $dA$) depend only on the initial and final states, my quantity $\delta M$ is not an exact differential because it also depends on the state of the surroundings. I don't know how to reconcile the two quantities then.

Also, I am interested in deriving $\delta M$ (or $dA$) with as few assumptions as possible. Do you think that the way I derived it from $dU=TdS-pdV$ as $\delta M :=-dU-pdV+TdS$ was just a lucky guess or is it valid?

I don't see how your $/delta M$ depends on the state of the surroundings.  $/delta$  $M$ is the maximum work that could in principle be extracted, given a differential step in the state of the system and the extensive macrovariables over which to do work.  Whether the surroundings can have that much work done on them would not appear to enter in.

I think your method of guessing $\delta M$ may be a helpful heuristic, but I don't know how to show how it follows from $dU = TdS - pdV$ without reference to entropy and the second law.

On second thought, maybe it's as simple as saying: $dU = -dW + dQ = -dW^{rev} - dW^{nonrev} + dQ^{rev} + dQ^{nonrev}$, so
$dW^{nonrev} = -dU - pdV + TdS + dQ^{nonrev}$, then
$\delta W = dW^{nonrev, max} = -dU - pdV + TdS$ because $dQ^{nonrev, max} = 0$ by the 2nd law.

I have one question more. If enthalpy is defined as $H=U+pV$ and if I differentiate that, I get $dH = dU + pdV + Vdp$. But you said: " $dU + PdV \equiv dH$ What is the most general definition of $dH$?

Your maximum free work function
$$M\equiv U_1-U_2 +p_s(V_1-V_2) -T_{s}(S_1-S_2)$$
is the negative Gibbs free energy change of a process occurring at constant temperature and pressure. The Gibbs free energy is
$$G\equiv U+pV-TS;$$
inserting the temperature and pressure and considering the final vs. initial state gives
$$\Delta G=U_2-U_1 +p_s(V_2-V_1) -T_{s}(S_2-S_1)=-M.$$
Thus, any relevant derivations or conclusions involving $\Delta G$ can also be applied to $-M$. Indeed, $\Delta G$ is negative (and $M$ positive) for a spontaneous process occurring in a system in thermal and mechanical contact with its surroundings.
